# How Simulink determines the amplitute of the carrier in PWM generator

Tags: pwm, power-electronics

In Matlab/Simulink, we can use the PWM generator block in order to create pulses. 
So, according to this method, the carrier is compared to the reference signal in order to create the pulses.

In order to do so, as you can see in the picture below, the PWM block requires the carrier frequency but not the carrier amplitude. I can not understand how the carrier amplitude is calculated.

[image]

Comment: A carrier-based three-level PWM method is used. The modulating signal (Uref input) ... need i say more

Comment: @Jak If I get it right, the amplitude of the carrier depends on the amplitude of Uref?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt read the block help and/or look under the block mask.

The reference carrier is +-1 and thus this block is expecting a PU Uref.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did some research and I saw the block that is illustrated in your answer but I was not sure because I thought that if this block works only under pu variables, it shoud be noted in the Matlab documentation. But it's not.